# Second differences of primes determined by increasing first differences: every positive even integer?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Suppose that $p(1)$ and $p(2)$ are primes.  For $n > 2$, let $p(n)$ be the least prime $p$ such that $p-2p(n-1)+p(n-2)>0$.  Does $p(n)-2p(n-1)+p(n-2)$ range through all the even positive integers?

Here are a few thoughts, based on comments.  Let $s(n) = p(n)-2p(n-1)+p(n-2)$.

(1)  Allow $p(1)$ to be any integer (not necessarily prime or positive).

(2)  Interpret "range through all even positive integers" to allow odd $s(1)$.

(3)  The main question is this:  what happens in the case $p(1) = 2$ and $p(2) = 3$?

(4)  What's the least choice of $p(2)$ for which there's a number $p(1) < p(2)$ such that some even positive integer is not $s(n)$ for any n?

Example for (3):  for $p(1)=2$ and $p(2)=3$, we have
$$(p(n)) = (2,3,5,11,19,29,41,59,79,101,\dots)$$
$$(s(n)) = (1,4,2,2,2,6,2,2,4,4,4,2,6,2,\dots)$$
$$(f(n)) = (3,2,6,18,46,45,70,56,59,26,\dots),$$
where $f(n)$ is the position at which $2n$ first appears in $(s(n))$.
Every even positive integer up to $120$ occurs among the first $30,000$ terms of $s(n)$.

Comment: Please change the title to include the question.  Even "On a difference of differences of consecutive primes" is not specific enough.

Comment: Do you mean $p(n) - 2 p(n-1) + p(n-2)$?  And even **positive** integers?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry ??  Ramified where?  And for that matter, what are $p_1$ and $p_2$?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry:  Ah, thanks for clarifying $p_1$ and $p_2$ --- I had indeed missed the fact that these were arbitrary.  I'm still not clear on where they're supposed to be ramified.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry:  It would really be better if you answered the question.

Comment: i've changed my mind, perhaps it is true after all.

Comment: This is basically a more complicated variant of Polignac's conjecture http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polignac%27s_conjecture .  Given that the latter conjecture is already hopelessly difficult, I don't see why one would expect to be able to resolve the current question, although the same probabilistic heuristics that strongly suggest Polignac's conjecture to be true would also apply here to suggest that this conjecture is probably true as well.

Comment: Another way to look at this is to consider "generalized power sequences", where one considers a sequence such that each kth difference is positive, and then one asks how bounded such a sequence is (or what range the kth difference has).  I see this as not far from asking if any "positive squarish" subsequence contained in the primes must have unbounded coefficient.  Note that if the second difference were constant for long, one would have a successful prime-producing quadratic polynomial. I have a related question on squares here. Gerhard "Giving Another Avenue Of Research" Paseman, 2015.05.15